# How I can get number of group from response?

Tags: solr

I am using apache solr 4. 
I am using query with group=true.

My query params is     "group=true&group.field=company_id"

How I can get number of group? 
In solr response only number of all rows and number of rows in every group.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `ngroups` parameter to true to get the count of group

Add `group.ngroups=true` to your querystring to achieve this.

More details in [this documentation.](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing)

Comment: @user2245564 - glad to be of help. Please mark this as an answer - it helps those who search for something similar.